# Passing arrays to remote server using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array in a bash script that contains ip addresses. I ssh to all of them one by one and use here-doc to run multiple commands on each server. From each server, I want to again ssh to all the servers and run some commands. Below is some code.

```
for i in "${IP_ADDRESSES[@]}"; do
ssh -i "$LOCAL_PEM_FILE" "$USER"@"$i" bash << HERE
    for j in "${IP_ADDRESSES[@]}"; do
    echo \$j
HERE
done
```

I was expecting $j to be list of all the ips that I can iterate one by one just like I am doing with i in the first for loop. Instead, j comes out as one single space delimited string containing all the ips.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array in the *here document* block doesn't need double quote:

```
for i in "${IP_ADDRESSES[@]}"; do
  ssh -i "$LOCAL_PEM_FILE" "${USER}@${i}" bash <<-HERE
    for j in ${IP_ADDRESSES[@]}; do
      echo \$j
    done
HERE
done
```

This works because you don't have any space in your IP address array.

If you would have elements with spaces, you can do the same using the bash parameter expansion operator `Q`.

```
for j in ${IP_ADDRESSES[@]@Q}; do ...
```

This adds single quote between each array element.

Comment: I learnt something totally new today! Stackoverflow never stops to amaze me and makes me realize how much more there is to know.